# Operator '=' is not defined for types 'Integer' and 'IQueryable(Of Integer)'

Tags: vb.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-2

This is giving me a headache. I have this link query here that grabs an ID

```
Dim mclassID = From x In db.SchoolClasses Where x.VisitDateID = _visitdateID Select x.ClassID
```

And then later on I have this linq query

`ViewData("Staff") = From t In db.Staffs Where t.ClassID = mclassID Select t`

Any help would be much appreciated. I've tried quite a few things but to no avail. I've attempted casting, converting, Is operand, etc.

Comment: Is the VB.NET equality operator ==?

Comment: Sorry, can't undo comment upvote. Indeed, it's `=`.

Comment: Negative :/ I've tried that. I'm generally a c# guy, but this project requires me to write in vb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `myClassID` is an anonymous `IQueryable`. You need to force it into another type (`List` is my favorite), and then pull it out of that type. So if you were to select it into a `List(Of Integer)` you could then extract the `First()` one since it would be the only. You could try something like this:

```
Dim myClassIDList As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)( _
    From x In db.SchoolClasses Where x.VisitDateID = _visitdateID Select x.ClassID)

Dim myClassID as Integer = myClassIDList.First()
```

Comment: It was answered so fast that I had to wait a few mins

Comment: You don't have to stuff the query into a list in order to call `First`.  Also, it'd be better to call `ToList` if you want a list, rather than passing it into a `List` constructor.  Also, you probably want `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` instead of `First`.

Comment: @bdukes - I agree. There are several ways to accomplish the same result. I was even thinking there might be a more direct route to grab the integer. I did say, though, that the List is my favorite.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but would it help to wrap the right-side of the equation in parenthesis?  I.e.:

```
ViewData("Staff") = (From t In db.Staffs Where t.ClassID = mclassID Select t)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change this

```
Dim mclassID = From x In db.SchoolClasses Where x.VisitDateID = _visitdateID Select x.ClassID
```

to select a single instance or the first instance, otherwise it does as its reporting, returning an `IEnumerable`, which causes your error later.

Or you could change your second statement to something like

```
ViewData("Staff") = From t In db.Staffs Where mclassID.Contains(t.ClassID) Select t
```

taking advantage of the `mclassID` as an `IEnumerable` of int.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548743.aspx) operator, you can have multiple results returned.  If you are only expecting one result (i.e. you are selecting by a primary key), then you can use [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156472.aspx) or [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359429.aspx) (depending on whether there is guaranteed to be a result) to get just that one.

```
Dim mclassID = (From x In db.SchoolClasses _
               Where x.VisitDateID = _visitdateID _
               Select x.ClassID).SingleOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the errors in Output if you set appropriate options: -

Navigate VS2010 menus to Tools/Options/Projects and solutions/Build and Run/
Set MSBuild Project build output verbosity to "Detailed"

I had a similar error that wasn't showing in the Error list, but with this options setting I saw: -
error BC30452: Operator '=' is not defined for types 'System.Nullable(Of Integer)' and 'Integer'.
from this statement: -
If tqGDBChart.UserIsGroupAdmin(Userid, Groupid) = 0 Then   'User is not a group admin for this group

Easily fixed it with an intermediate variable.

```
Dim GroupAdminCount As Integer = tqGDBChart.UserIsGroupAdmin(Userid, Groupid)
If GroupAdminCount = 0 Then   'User is not a group admin for this group
```

Answer (score -1):

have you tried:

```
ViewData("Staff") = From t In db.Staffs Where t.ClassID.equals(mclassID)  Select t
```

Comment: what about .contains instead of .equals ?